# Group logs by latest timestamp, by day

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dsl

Please bear with me as I am very new to Elastic Search. Below is the schema of the data piping into Elastic Search. The "updated_at" field at the very bottom is the "timestamp." A new record of this data is piped into ES every two hours, with an "updated_at" timestamp as well. I would like to write a DSL query that only pulls each record by the maximum (latest) timestamp of each day, but I'm not sure how or where to start. I tried using aggs but didn't get too far.

```
  {
    "_index" : "analyticspeoplecountbycompany",
    "_type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany",
    "_id" : "2hmEZW4Bxxxxx",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "data" : {
        "result" : {
          "result" : [
            {
              "EntityName" : "",
              "Type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany",
              "Value" : null,
              "Template" : {
                "Company" : "XXX",
                "Claimed" : "2",
                "Not Claimed" : "49",
                "Type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany"
              }
            },          
            {
              "EntityName" : "",
              "Type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany",
              "Value" : null,
              "Template" : {
                "Company" : "YYY",
                "Claimed" : "75",
                "Not Claimed" : "108",
                "Type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany"
              }
            },
            {
              "EntityName" : "",
              "Type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany",
              "Value" : null,
              "Template" : {
                "Company" : "ZZZ",
                "Claimed" : "34",
                "Not Claimed" : "92",
                "Type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany"
              }
            },
            {
              "EntityName" : "",
              "Type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany",
              "Value" : null,
              "Template" : {
                "Company" : "AAA",
                "Claimed" : "97",
                "Not Claimed" : "260",
                "Type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany"
              }              
            {
              "EntityName" : "",
              "Type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany",
              "Value" : null,
              "Template" : {
                "Company" : "BBB",
                "Claimed" : "92",
                "Not Claimed" : "269",
                "Type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "type" : "analytics_PeopleCountByCompany",
        "description" : "Count of People by Company",
        "updated_at" : "2019-11-13T16:06:47.704Z"
```